# How to join two tables with Linq in an MVC controller

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have two sql database tables with a 1:n relationship. For my ASP.NET MVC-solution I have enabled EF-code-first-migration and the proper DBContext and classes established.

I would like to write an MVC-controller that joins both tables in order to select specific records for display in a view.

Here are the two classes:

```
        public class Tbl_Group_Communities : Entity
{
    public string GKZ { get; set; }
    public int G_ID { get; set; }
}

    public class Katastralgemeinden : Entity
{
    public string KGNr { get; set; }
    public string KGName { get; set; }
    public string GKZ { get; set; }
    public string GemeindeName { get; set; }
}
```

So far I have been able to come up with a working controller for the tables  by themselves but not joined. Below the working controller for the first class:

```
            public IEnumerable<Tbl_Group_Communities> Get()
    {
        var entities = UnitOfWork.GetAll<Tbl_Group_Communities>().ToList();
        return entities;
    }
```

I think, the join can be done with Linq but I have no idea how/where to start. 
The common key for both tables is GKZ; so the join should be established via GKZ. And then I need to select specific records from the joined records where G_ID = a certain value.

If someone could give me some help, I'd be very thankful.
Manu

Comment: I'm sure somebody can show you how to do the join, but I would advise you research on how to configure [code first relationships](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx). If you setup the proper models with navigation properties it is pretty simple. I would advise looking into ViewModels.

Comment: Do you mean you can't find any documentation on how to write the `Join` statement? Apart from that, it's not clear what `UnitOfWork` can produce. Does it also provide `Katastralgemeinden`? And if so, what does `GetAll` return? If it's `IEnumerable`, joining isn't efficient at all.

Comment: I could find documentation, but since I am pretty new with C# and  MVC-controllers the docus were more confusing than helping. UnitOfWork does also provide Katastralgemeinden. I thought GetAll does return all records, which was just a check that for one table the controller does work. What would be more efficient than IEnumerable?

Comment: If you join two `IEnumerable`s, the data of both tables will be fetched into memory by two queries (that probably return lots of data) and then joined in memory. When you join two `IQueryable` (coming from the same context), the join will be translated into one efficient SQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do inner join as shown below.

**Assumption :** Hope your table names are like `Tbl_Group_Communities` and `Katastralgemeinden`.In other words same name as the class names.

```
from s in db.Tbl_Group_Communities
join sa in db.Katastralgemeinden on s.GKZ equals sa.GKZ
where s.G_ID == 1
select s
```

You can learn more about `join` here : [**Join Operators**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896266(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - here is my controller that works:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Query;
using IndireKat.Data.Contracts;
using IndireKat.Data.Contracts.Entities;
using IndireKat.Shared.Framework.Security;

namespace Presentation.Host.Controllers
{
    public class KatastralgemeindenController : BaseODataController
    {
        private readonly IIdentityStorage identityStorage;

        public KatastralgemeindenController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IIdentityStorage identityStorage)
        {
            UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            this.identityStorage = identityStorage;
        }

        [Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
        public IQueryable<Katastralgemeinden> Get()
        {
            IIndireKatPrincipal indireKatPrincipal = identityStorage.GetPrincipal();

            var comunityIds = UnitOfWork.GetAll<UserGroup>()
                .Where(group => group.Id == indireKatPrincipal.GroupId)
                .SelectMany(group => group.Tbl_Group_Communities).Select(comunity => comunity.GKZ).ToList();

            IQueryable<Katastralgemeinden> result = null;

            if (comunityIds.Any())
            {
                result = UnitOfWork.GetAll<Katastralgemeinden>().Where(company => comunityIds.Contains(company.GKZ));
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Regards, Manu